# Android Tab Scroll View

Tags: android, xml, layout, tabs

Currently I have three sets of data that are separate from one another. I am implementing a HorizontalScrollView and while it does the trick of displaying all three separate sets of data, the data all itself doesn't seem all that "separate" from one another. The design just seems impractical.

I would like to implement a tab view of some sort,(with three tabs) that the user can use to navigate amongst the three sets data (Each separate set in its own tab).

Is there anyway to implement this in a way where in each tab I just have a relative-layout containing the child views which will display the data?

Ive seached all over Google to only find demonstrations that treat this strategy as the whole activity. Well my HorizontalScrollView is only a section of the display. So the tutorials I find dont do me much good.

Heres an XML snippet of the current HorizontalScrollView with child TextViews. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Please and thank you!

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_data"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button_2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_scrollview">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview1_dataset_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview2_dataset_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:textColor="#006599"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageview1_dataset_1"
                android:layout_width="55dp"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:contentDescription="current_weather_icon_from_noaa"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:padding="1px"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview3_dataset_2"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview4_dataset_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="82dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:textColor="#004163"
                android:textSize="45sp" 
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview5_dataset_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:textColor="#6b6b6b"
                android:textSize="25sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview6_dataset_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="75dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:textColor="#383838"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview7_dataset_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textview_details_windspeed"
                android:text="Wind-Speed:"
                android:textColor="#383838"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview8_dataset_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:textColor="#006599"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/idtextview8_dataset_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="115dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:textColor="#383838"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview9_dataset_3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
                android:textColor="#006599"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to implement this with `TabHost`.

Comment: Thank-You :-) after some research and implementation got it going!